# How do I use Core Data functionality with a predefined XML store?

Tags: objective-c, xml, core-data

I believe this is a simple question, but Googling hasn't led me somewhere so far. Here's the case: I have an XML that contains the data for an iPad app and I need to 'query' it to retrieve data. I'm used to working with Core Data, but from a we-don't-have-initial-data point of view.

So, how do I wrap Core Data around the XML file, making it the back-end for the persistant store. I only need reads and the data is consistent. How do I do this/proceed? Any help is greatly appreciated.

Kind regards,

Reinder

Comment: [Here's a nice hands-on example tutorial](http://cocoadevcentral.com/articles/000085.php) using Core Data.  If you read toward the bottom, there is discussion regarding its use with XML.

Comment: Are you talking about an xml file that was previously created with Core Data or an arbitrary one?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will have to parse manually your XML file, create Core Data objects from the results and save them. Here's a [good tutorial](http://www.edumobile.org/iphone/iphone-programming-tutorials/parsing-an-xml-file/) on how to parse XML under iOS, as far as I understood with Core Data you won't have problems.